# Declaring an interface that acts as an array with a starting point of 1

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So long story short for complicated reasons I need to be able to declare an interface (that uses an array signature) to start at 1, or at least have [0] be a null. Is this possible?

I've already tried this:

```
interface ItemCollection<T> extends Collection
{
    [index: number]: [null, ...Function[]];


    addComp(): void;
}
```

Which obviously just says, "ItemCollection[0...] is a tuple", not what I want.

Tried this too:

```
interface ItemCollection<T> extends Collection
{
    [0]: null;
    [index: number]: Function;
}
```

However I just get an error saying, "Property '[0]' of type 'null' is not assignable to numeric index type 'Function'.ts(2412)"
So clearly not the answer.

I can do it using a standard variable:

```
tmp: [null, ...Function[]];
```

This works perfectly, but it's not the same.

Comment: This is a language feature, as you probably know, in Javascript and TypeScript indexes start at zero. You will need to create a function to implement the behavior you expect

Comment: Yeah I thought that would be the case. Was hoping to do some funny buggers with type declaration files to get it to throw an error if I tried accessing the array at index 0, but I guess not. 
For some reason the API i'm dealing with decided, "fuck it," and some of their arrays start at 0 and others at 1...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. But it required a lot of recursive magic:

First let's declare utils to add/remove element from tuple:

```js
type PrependTuple<A, T extends Array<any>> =
  A extends undefined ? T : 
  (((a: A, ...b: T) => void) extends (...a: infer I) => void ? I : [])

type RemoveFirstFromTuple<T extends any[]> = 
  T['length'] extends 0 ? undefined :
  (((...b: T) => void) extends (a, ...b: infer I) => void ? I : [])

type FirstFromTuple<T extends any[]> =
  T['length'] extends 0 ? undefined : T[0]
```

Then we have to declare utils that will create tuple with `N` items:

```js
type NumberToTuple<N extends number, L extends Array<any> = []> = {
  true: L;
  false: NumberToTuple<N, PrependTuple<1, L>>;
}[L['length'] extends N ? "true" : "false"];
```

this will recursive increase size of `L` tuple until it will be as long as we want.

Next step reverse tuple util (based on the same idea)

```js
type ReverseTuple<T extends Array<any>, L extends Array<any> = []> = {
  true: L;
  false: ReverseTuple<T, PrependTuple< T[L['length']] , L>>;
}[L['length'] extends T['length'] ? "true" : "false"];

type R4 = ReverseTuple<[1, 2, 3, 4]>; // [4,3,2,1]
```

And last needed util to decrease number:

```js
type Decrease<I extends number> = RemoveFirstFromTuple<NumberToTuple<I>>['length']
```

It's creating tuple with exact length and remove first element. Result is size of cut tuple.

And cream de la cream: iterator that will apply logic:

```
type Iter<N extends number, Items extends any[], L extends Array<any> = []> = {
  true: L;
  false: Iter<N, Items, PrependTuple<L['length'] extends N ? unknown : Items[Decrease<L['length']>]  , L>>
}[L["length"] extends N ? "true" : "false"];
```

Iteration is made in the sam way, but in final step (when `L['length'] extends N`) we prepend `unknown` to tuple. Because we increase size of final tuple (Result['length'] === Items['length'] + 1) we have to decrease index.

Also because we prepend (not append) we have to reverse our tuple. So final generic will look like this:

```js
type FromFirstTuple<T extends Array<any>> = ReverseTuple<Iter<PrependTuple<1, T>['length'], T>>

type Result = FromFirstTuple<[1,2,3]> // [unknown, 1, 2, 3]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20PrependTuple%3CA%2C%20T%20extends%20Array%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20A%20extends%20undefined%20%3F%20T%20%3A%20%0D%0A%20%20(((a%3A%20A%2C%20...b%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20extends%20(...a%3A%20infer%20I)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3F%20I%20%3A%20%5B%5D)%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RemoveFirstFromTuple%3CT%20extends%20any%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20%0D%0A%20%20T%5B'length'%5D%20extends%200%20%3F%20undefined%20%3A%0D%0A%20%20(((...b%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20extends%20(a%2C%20...b%3A%20infer%20I)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3F%20I%20%3A%20%5B%5D)%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FirstFromTuple%3CT%20extends%20any%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20T%5B'length'%5D%20extends%200%20%3F%20undefined%20%3A%20T%5B0%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20NumberToTuple%3CN%20extends%20number%2C%20L%20extends%20Array%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20true%3A%20L%3B%0D%0A%20%20false%3A%20NumberToTuple%3CN%2C%20PrependTuple%3C1%2C%20L%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%5BL%5B'length'%5D%20extends%20N%20%3F%20%22true%22%20%3A%20%22false%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ReverseTuple%3CT%20extends%20Array%3Cany%3E%2C%20L%20extends%20Array%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20true%3A%20L%3B%0D%0A%20%20false%3A%20ReverseTuple%3CT%2C%20PrependTuple%3C%20T%5BL%5B'length'%5D%5D%20%2C%20L%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%5BL%5B'length'%5D%20extends%20T%5B'length'%5D%20%3F%20%22true%22%20%3A%20%22false%22%5D%3B%0D%0Atype%20R4%20%3D%20ReverseTuple%3C%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%5D%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Decrease%3CI%20extends%20number%3E%20%3D%20RemoveFirstFromTuple%3CNumberToTuple%3CI%3E%3E%5B'length'%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Iter%3CN%20extends%20number%2C%20Items%20extends%20any%5B%5D%2C%20L%20extends%20Array%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20true%3A%20L%3B%0D%0A%20%20false%3A%20Iter%3CN%2C%20Items%2C%20PrependTuple%3CL%5B'length'%5D%20extends%20N%20%3F%20unknown%20%3A%20Items%5BDecrease%3CL%5B'length'%5D%3E%5D%20%20%2C%20L%3E%3E%0D%0A%7D%5BL%5B%22length%22%5D%20extends%20N%20%3F%20%22true%22%20%3A%20%22false%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FromFirstTuple%3CT%20extends%20Array%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%20ReverseTuple%3CIter%3CPrependTuple%3C1%2C%20T%3E%5B'length'%5D%2C%20T%3E%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Result%20%3D%20FromFirstTuple%3C%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%3E%20%2F%2F%20%5Bunknown%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%5D%0D%0A)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you were looking for... (Also consider marking this as accepted)

```
type Unshift<T extends any[]> =
    ((a: null, ...b: T) => void) extends ((...ab: infer R) => void)
    ? R : never

type foo = Unshift<[1, 2, 3]> // [null, 1, 2, 3]
```

[Demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Unshift%3CT%20extends%20any%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20((a%3A%20null%2C%20...b%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20extends%20((...ab%3A%20infer%20R)%20%3D%3E%20void)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20R%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20foo%20%3D%20Unshift%3C%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%3E%20%2F%2F%20%5Bnull%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%5D)